# How can the bot says the message over and over without the code being duplicated or looped

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I am trying to make a battle command, but I don't know how to make the bot resend the message without me duplicating the code in the python file.

```
  await ctx.send("Player 1, what will you do now? OPTIONS: Fight, Defense, Items, Surrender")
  def check(m):
    return m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author
  send = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
  
  await ctx.send("Player 2, what will you do now? OPTIONS: Fight, Defense, Items, Surrender")
  def check(m):
    return m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author
  send = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
-- TURN 1 --
Bot: Player 1, what will you do now? OPTIONS: Fight, Defense, Items, Surrender
Player 1: Fight
Bot: Player 2, what will you do now? OPTIONS: Fight, Defense, Items, Surrender
Player 2: Defense
-- TURN 2 --
Bot: Player 1, what will you do now? OPTIONS: Fight, Defense, Items, Surrender
Player 1: Defense
Bot: Player 2, what will you do now? OPTIONS: Fight, Defense, Items, Surrender
Player 2: Fight
```

And repeat the turns until one of the players are defeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it would be:

```py
aysnc def action(ctx, player):
    await ctx.send(f"{player}, what will you do now? OPTIONS: Fight, Defense, Items, Surrender")
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author
    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    if "defense" in response.content.lower():
        #Do stuff
    elif "fight" in response.content.lower():
        #Do stuff
    elif "Items" in response.content.lower():
        #Do stuff
    elif "Surender" in response.content.lower():
        #Do stuff
    elif "end" in response.content.lower():
        return False
    return True

async def turn(ctx, nb):
    await ctx.send("-- Turn {nb} --")
    for player in ["player 1", "player 2"]:
        action = await action(ctx, player)
    await ctx.send("Game ended") if not action else await turn(ctx, nb+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop for this. Put your condition inside and return or break it once the condition matches. The below code will give you an idea of how to do it.

```
def check(m):
    return m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author
while True:
    await ctx.send("Player 1, what will you do now? OPTIONS: Fight, Defense, Items, Surrender")
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    if msg.content == 'Fight':
        pass
    elif msg.content == 'Defense':
        pass
    elif msg.content == 'Items':
        pass
    elif msg.content == 'Surrender':
        pass

    # You can end the Loop Once the Condition Matches, Example:
    if health >= 0:
        return
```